# Intellij Idea keep having pop-ups that can't be close autmatically

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, popup, type-hinting

Idea always has pop-ups that automatically appear but cannot be automatically retracted.

You see that there are multiple overlapping pop-ups as I type, and they won't automatically disappear even after I complete the code.

[image]

I don't remember when or how my IDE became like this. I am okay with automatic pop-ups like hints or completion, but they will always disappear after I finish typing. The current pop-up does not disappear automatically.

How can I solve this? Thanks so much for your time!

I tried googling it or asking GPT.

Comment: Please collect the logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data) and send logs to me: changjiong.liu@jetbrains.com , only a screenshot can't find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely some exceptions are thrown (possibly by some plugin). Are there exceptions in [the log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)?